# How to use list comprehensions to make a dict having list of list as values

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I Have a list as following and I want to convert that as output shown below using List comprehensions. Any help is appreciated.

```
a = [{'type': 'abc', 'values': 1},
     {'type': 'abc', 'values': 2},
     {'type': 'abc', 'values': 3},
     {'type': 'xyz', 'values': 4},
     {'type': 'xyz', 'values': 5},
     {'type': 'pqr', 'values': 6},
     {'type': 'pqr', 'values': 8},
     {'type': 'abc', 'values': 9},
     {'type': 'mno', 'values': 10},
     {'type': 'def', 'values': 11}]
```

This is the output I am expecting.

```
output = {'abc': [1,2,3,9], 'xyz': [4,5], 'pqr': [6,8], 'mno': [10], 'def': [11]}
```

Comment: Might I suggest *not* using a list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

a = [{'type': 'abc', 'values': 1},
     {'type': 'abc', 'values': 2},
     {'type': 'abc', 'values': 3},
     {'type': 'xyz', 'values': 4},
     {'type': 'xyz', 'values': 5},
     {'type': 'pqr', 'values': 6},
     {'type': 'pqr', 'values': 8},
     {'type': 'abc', 'values': 9},
     {'type': 'mno', 'values': 10},
     {'type': 'def', 'values': 11}]

typegetter = itemgetter('type')
valuesgetter = itemgetter('values')

groups = groupby(sorted(a, key=typegetter), key=typegetter)

print {k:list(map(valuesgetter, v)) for k, v in groups}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [{'type': 'abc', 'values': 1},
     {'type': 'abc', 'values': 2},
     {'type': 'abc', 'values': 3},
     {'type': 'xyz', 'values': 4},
     {'type': 'xyz', 'values': 5},
     {'type': 'pqr', 'values': 6},
     {'type': 'pqr', 'values': 8},
     {'type': 'abc', 'values': 9},
     {'type': 'mno', 'values': 10},
     {'type': 'def', 'values': 11}]

output = {}
for item in a:
    output[item['type']] = [item['values']] if output.get(item['type'], None) is None else output[item['type']] + [item['values']]
print output
```